# Can't read native C++ BYTE * in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, byte, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to read the passport information (MRZ) in a reader that uses Win CE 6. NET.
vendor's API is written in C + +

```
//[C + +]
typedef int (* CRXCALLBACK) (BYTE *pRecvBuff, nDataLen int);
int FAR PASCAL EXPORT CRX_Open (CRXCALLBACK lpDataCallback);
```

This is my VB.NET Implementation

```
'[VB.NET]
Public Class CRX
  Public Delegate Function CRXCALLBACK (ByVal pRecvBuff As System.IntPtr, ByVal nDataLen As   Integer) As Integer
  <DllImport("Mrz.dll", EntryPoint:="CRX_Open", SetLastError:=True)> _
  Public Shared Function CRX_Open(ByVal lpDataCallback As CRXCALLBACK) As Integer
  End Function
End Class
```

In a form

```
Private Sub CRX_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 If CRX.CRX_Open(AddressOf MrzReaderCallback) <> CRX_ERR_SUCCESS Then
   MessageBox.Show("CRX_Open Failed")
 End Sub
Private Function MrzReaderCallback(ByVal pRecvBuff As System.IntPtr, ByVal nDataLen As Integer) As Integer
        Try
            Dim str As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pRecvBuff)
            MsgBox(str)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End Try
        Return CRX_ERR_SUCCESS
```

but when I receive the `pRecvBuff` content using `Marshal.PtrToStringUni (pRecvBuff, nDataLen)` returns me unreadable characters

Any suggestions for me, what am I doing wrong?

regards

Ivan

Comment: Wrong calling convention.  CRX_Open is okay, but not the delegate.  You'll need to apply the `<UnmanagedFunctionPointer>` attribute on the delegate to tell the CLR that it is Cdecl.  No idea if that's supported by CF.  PtrToStringUni() is wrong too, that's Ansi.

Comment: The only calling convention for the CF is `<CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Winapi)`, and when i used  the `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)> ` attribute on the delegate returns me {System.NotSupportedException} 0x80131515

Comment: Make that "definitely not supported on CF".  You can't pinvoke this.  Contact the vendor and ask for a change in the calling convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i solve using this code

```
 Private Function MrzReaderCallback(ByVal pRecvBuff As System.IntPtr, ByVal nDataLen As Integer) As Integer
        Dim b As Byte
        Dim c As Char
        Dim s As String = ""
        Try
            For x As Integer = 8 To nDataLen
                b = Marshal.ReadByte(pRecvBuff, x)
                If b = &H0 Or b = &H1 Or b = &H2 Or b = &H3 Or b = &H60 Then
                    b = &H20
                ElseIf b <> &HD Then
                    c = Convert.ToChar(b)
                    s &= c.ToString
                End If
            Next
            SetText(s, txtMRZ)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error ex")
        End Try
        Return mi3api.MachineReadableDataProcessingAPI.CRX_ERR_SUCCESS
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Marhsal.PtrToStringUni`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringuni.aspx) expects the buffer (`IntPtr`) to contain a byte array comprising a unicode string.

If the C++ API wasn't using Unicode, you may need [`Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringansi.aspx) or [`Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringbstr.aspx) instead.

Comment: `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`. is not supported by CF and `Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR` is returning me a null value